# React Calculator: Input Tag value displays decimals and other symbols incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am making a calculator using React and essentially I programmed the buttons to trigger a function `numberDisplay()` that appends a corresponding value of the button pressed to a string (the state). My question is why do symbol characters such as the period look as though they are being pushed in front of the string in the input field when they aren't. For example I press buttons in this order 1 ,3 , 5 the input field displays correctly `135` However when I enter 1, 3, 5. It displays the decimal in the front like so `.`135`.

I do a console log and the decimal is definitely the end of the string so I am very confused as to why the decimal is pushed to the front. Lastly operator buttons reset my state however I tested and the symbols `& + -` and `/` all get pushed to the front in the input field.

```
class Calculator extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        expFrag:'0',
        expression:''
    };
};

    componentDidMount(){
        this.keypress();
    }

    numberDisplay = (input) => {
        //decimal isnt placed at the end of the string. 
        //decimal  replaces "0" at the beginning of the state.
        if(this.state.expFrag.includes('.') === true && input === '.'){
            return;
        }else{
            if( this.state.expFrag === '0' && input === '0'){
                return;
            }else if (this.state.expFrag === '0' && input != '0'){
                this.setState({
                    expFrag:input,
                    expression:this.state.expression
                });
            }else{
              this.setState({
                expFrag:this.state.expFrag.concat(input),
                expression:this.state.expression
              });
            };
        };
    };

};

appendReset = (operator) =>{
        this.numberDisplay(operator);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.expAppend()},10);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.resetExpFrag()},10);
    };

render(){
    return(
   <div>
         <h1>Calculator</h1>
         <div id="parent">
              <input id="display" dir="rtl" value={this.state.expFrag}/><br/>
              <div className="b">
                <button id="clearEntry" onClick={ () => this.clearEntry()}>CE</button>
                <button id="allClear" onClick={ () => this.clear()}>C</button>
                <button id="backspace" onClick={() => this.backspace()}>bck</button>
                <button id="division"onClick={() => this.appendReset('/')}>/</button>
             </div>
             <div className="b">
                <button id="seven" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('7')}>7</button> 
                <button id="eight" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('8')}>8</button>
                <button id="nine" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('9')}>9</button>
                <button id="multiply" onClick ={ () => this.appendReset('X')}>X</button>
             </div>
             <div className="b">
                <button id="six" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('6')}>6</button>
                <button id="five" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('5')}>5</button>
                <button id="four" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('4')}>4</button>
                <button id="subtract" onClick ={() => this.appendReset('-')}>-</button>
             </div>
             <div className="b">
                <button id="one" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('1')}>1</button>
                <button id="two" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('M')}>2</button>
                <button id="three" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('P')}>3</button>
                <button id="add" onClick ={() => this.appendReset('+')}>+</button>
             </div>
             <div className="b">
                <button id="sign" onClick ={() => this.sign()}>+/-</button>
                <button id="zero" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('0')}>0</button>
                <button id="decimal" onClick ={() => this.numberDisplay('.')}>.</button>
                <button id="result">=</button>
             </div>
             <div className="b">
              <button id="leftParenthesis">(</button>
              <button id="rightParenthesis">)</button>
              <button id="test" onClick ={()=> this.show()}>TEST</button>
              <button id="test" onClick ={()=> this.numberDisplay('&')}>&</button>


             </div>
        </div>
    </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the input box has the attribute `dir="rtl"`

Remove `dir="rtl"` to fix it. To make the text appear on the right-side of the inputbox, use `style="text-align:right"` instead.

```html
<label>dir="rtl"</label>
<br/><input dir="rtl" value="123." />
<br/><br/>
<label>dir="ltr" (default)</label>
<br/><input style="text-align:right" value="123." />
```

Comment: @KamalCarmichael juicy.